# Ориентация экрана в LibGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Как настроить автоповорот экрана в LibGDX для android? Можно ли попросту в манифесте записать и landscape и portrait, или же есть какой-то другой способ?

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на данный вопрос больше не нужен. В манифесте, в блоке  вместо landscape или portrait необходимо указать user.
Тогда строка будет выглядеть так: `android:screenOrientation="user"`